# TypeError: "range.getRange is not a function" when iterating through rows

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I want to iterate through table rows in a google spreadsheet and for each row check if the first cell is empty (by `first cell` I mean the cell of the column 1 of the table).

```
function myFunction(range){
  for(var i = 1 ; i < 70; i++){
    if (range.getRange(i,1).isBlank()){
      Logger.log('is blank')
    } 
  }
}
```

It gives me:

> "TypeError: range.getRange is not a function".

Any idea why and how to fix this?

Comment: How are you calling `myFunction()`, are you sure you are passing it a valid object that has `getRange()` method, ie log `range` and see if it is what it is supposed to be

Comment: Try to see what is `range` in the function body, use console log

Answer (score 0):

It looks that  you have executed the function for the script editor. In this case, `range` is a function parameter, the editor doesn't assign a value to it so this variable returns `undefined`. The error occurs because `undefined` hasn't a method named `getRange`.

As someone new to using Google Apps Script to extend Google Sheets, please read https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets.